# Does CSS have a :blur selector (pseudo-class)?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I know there is a `:focus` selector. I can't seem to find use of or documentation of a `:blur` selector. Is there one?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

There is no `:blur` pseudo-class in CSS.

The [dynamic pseudo-classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#dynamic-pseudos), like other pseudo-classes and in fact all other selectors, represent *states*; they do not represent *events* or *transitions between states* in terms of the document tree. To wit: the `:focus` pseudo-class represents an element that *is in* focus; it does not represent an element that has just *received* focus, nor does there exist a `:blur` pseudo-class to represent an element that has just *lost* focus.

Similarly, this applies to the `:hover` pseudo-class. While it represents an element which has a pointing device over it, there is neither a `:mouseover` pseudo-class for an element that has just been *pointed to* nor a `:mouseout` pseudo-class for an element that has just been *pointed away from*.

If you need to apply styles to an element that *is not in* focus, you have two choices:

1. Use `:not(:focus)` (with less browser support):

   ```
   input:not(:focus), button:not(:focus) {
       /* Styles for only form inputs and buttons that do not have focus */
   }
   ```
2. Declare a rule that applies to any element regardless of its focus state, and override for elements that have focus:

   ```
   input, button {
       /* Styles for all form inputs and buttons */
   }

   input:focus, button:focus {
       /* Styles for only form inputs and buttons that have focus */
   }
   ```

Comment: would `.button:not(:focus)` equal `.button`? They elect the same but the latter has a specificity of 10 and the first a specificity of 20.

Comment: @Torsten Walter: No, they're different; `.button` will match all elements with that class whether or not they are in focus, while `.button:not(:focus)` will never match the elements that are matched by `.button:focus`. The reason why you use `.button` and `.button:focus` together is to take advantage of the cascade. But, yes, the latter is less specific.

Comment: Right. I didn't think about it from that perspective.

Comment: What if you want to style something only after a user focused on it the left? For example, you wouldn't want to shout at someone for not entering a password when they load the page, only after they left the input.

Comment: @Marcel: Then you will need to use a JavaScript event handler, for example to update the element with a class corresponding to your desired styles. CSS only works with states and not events, which means as far as CSS is concerned, an element is either in focus or not in focus. In particular, it doesn't know whether or not the element has been focused since the page was loaded (unless you tell it by updating the DOM after the fact, something only a script can do).

Comment: @BoltClock That's ok. I know how to do it with JavaScript. I just hoped it was possible with CSS.

Answer (score 8):

No, CSS has no blur pseudo-selector, presumably because blur is more of an event than a state. (It would be unclear when something should lose its blur state).

Answer (score 4):

All regular selectors are by default not focussed. So you don't need a special blur selector.

These are the selectors by precedence.

```
.myButton
.myButton:hover
.myButton:focus
.myButton:active
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the general transition to set the blur transition.

```
.example {
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: 2s; /* This will happen after the hover state and can also be used for consistency on the overall experience */
  opacity: 0;
}
.example:hover {
  opacity: .8;
  transition-duration: .3s;
  transition-delay: .1s;
}
```