# CSS selector :contains() doesn't work with line breaks

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

```
<div>Some reallllly
realllyyy long text</div>
```

will render as `Some reallllly realllyyy long text` because HTML removes the line breaks.

But I can't find the `div` using the `:contains()` CSS selector because of the line break:

```
// Returns an empty array
$(':contains("Some reallllly realllyyy long text")');
```

Is there a way to select the div and ignore the line-break?

**Note**: I don't want to add the line break in the selector, I want to be able to select the `div` without knowing there is a line break (because I use the text that the user can see, and he can't see the line break)

Comment: Why don't you use some unique identifiers for your divs? What you are doing right now is basically the ugliest thing I've seen. `<div data-handle="asd-123">Some reallllly realllyyy long text</div>` would be much simpler to handle.

Comment: var str = "Some reallllly realllyyy long text";
str = str.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
$(':contains('+str+')');, Hey, can you try this

Comment: @slash197 In general, I agree with you, but this is not for front end javascript. This is to write functional tests (Selenium). So it's better to say "I click on button 'Validate'" rather than "I click on button '#superId'" because the first one has a functional meaning.

Comment: @MMM I'm looking for a solution. That's what stackoverflow is about you know...

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli: And I've given you one.

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli does my answer fits your needs ?

Comment: Also, `:contains()` is not a CSS selector (or at least, not anymore).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you could do is overriding the `:contains` selector :

```
$.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function( elem ) {
        return $(elem).text().replace(/(\n)+/g, " ").indexOf(arg) >= 0;
    };
});
```

See this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pCVLg/1/)**

With such a solution, you don't have to change anything in your code but only add this piece of code. But this is not a good practice. 
Of course you could name this selector other way. In this case, you could use both of the behaviours :

`$.expr[":"].mycontains`

See this other **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yfycm/)**

Comment: This won't work if there is more than one newline character in a row.

Comment: You should call "contains" something else, it's not a good idea to overwrite the default "contains" selector with one that does something subtly different.

Comment: Well, thanks. Now it does. But this is just for the idea. You can do anything you want with this.

Comment: @thirtydot: [An excellent use case for a prefix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11748141/can-i-force-jquery-to-use-sizzle-to-evaluate-a-selector-without-using-non-standa/11748913#11748913)

Answer (score 0):

The concept is very innefficient and so is my answer:

```
$("div").each(function () {
    if ($(this).text()replace(/(\n)+/g, " ") == "Some reallllly realllyyy long text") {
        // Do something
        $(this).css({color: 'red'});
    }
});
```

Remember that the browser just happens to render a collection of whitespace characters as a single space. Please rethink your approach.

Comment: Yeah not really efficient, but it does the job :). About the approach, see in the comments this is for functional validation so I need to select elements by their functional meaning (their label).

Comment: Actually, `.replace(/\n/g," ")` is better - your answer will only work with one newline, this one will replace all occourencies.

Comment: Thanks Kamil, however will that not generate more spaces than neccessary? Shouldn't it be like `.replace(/(\n)+/g, " ")`?