# What is the difference between :last and :last-of-type in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Please see this image:

[image]

Can someone explain the difference?

### Edit

Let me indicate what puzzles me. Notice that:

1. `$row.is('tr.items:last') === false`
2. `$row[0].id === $('tr.items:last')[0].id`

The two statements seem to contradict each other. The first tells us that `$row` is not the last of `tr.items`. But the second one tells that `$row` is exactly `$('tr.items:last')`, i.e. the last of `tr.items`.

No such thing occurs with the `:last-of-type` selector.

What is going on here?

Comment: Does `row[0] === $('tr.items:last')[0]` yield `true`?

Comment: Indeed it does - see another edit of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery does a different filter mechanism for `.is` when it comes to set filters like `:last`. The point is that it normally uses `.filter` on the current set and checks whether there are any elements left after filtering.

This works for cases such as:

```
$("<a></a><b></b>").is("b");  // true, there is a <b> after filtering
```

But for `:last` this fails, because such a filter is relative to the set. Consider a document with two  elements:

```
$("a:first").is("a:last");  // would be true if the same method was used,
                            // because in the set with the first <a> element,
                            // the last <a> element is that element. So filtering
                            // with `a:last` yields something, and `.is` gets you
                            // true.
```

This is in contrast with what you may expect. So, jQuery instead searches for `a:last` in the current context and checks whether `a:first` is apparent in that set.

The problem in your case is that `$(ev.target)` (in `handleKeyDown`) makes the context to be that input element and not the document (which is the usual case). No `tr.items` can be found in that context and you get `false`. This is arguably a bug in jQuery.

Anyway, what you can do is checking against a set instead. It is faster to use the corresponding functions, anyway:

```
$row.is( $("tr.items").last() );  // true
```

Comment: I still do not get it, but suppose everything is like you say it is. `$("tr.items").last()` is by far not the same as `$("tr.items:last")`. If I have a 100 rows, then the first expression obtains the 100 rows and returns the last, whereas the second one is expected to pinpoint just the last row. For me, it is like doing `SELECT` in sql and then filter the list in code vs doing  `SELECT WHERE` in the first place. I mean, no one doubts that the second form is the right one. So why are the relative selectors deprecated? CSS now has `:last-of-type`, which is exactly what I need.

Comment: @mark: My apologies, I was stretching it a bit. It is not deprecated but using those jQuery-only selectors disallows the (fast) CSS selector of the browser. But `:last`/`.last()` are the same - `:last` is applied after selecting the `tr.items`, which is what calling `.last()` does as well.

Comment: Let me summarize for me: **1.** `:last` is buggy. **2.** use either `.last()` or `:last-of-type`, where the latter is unavailable in old browsers (how old?), but may be really faster than `.last()` if  supported. Then comes the question - isn't jQuery supposed to spare us exactly these details? Shouldn't it implement `:last` as `:last-of-type` where supported and as `.last()` where is not?

Comment: @mark: `:last` and `:last-of-type` aren't the same thing. `:last` really just selects the last element of the matched elements, e.g. `tr:last` gives you the last `tr` element on the page. `tr:last-of-type` selects all `tr` that are the last of their siblings. If you have two tables, `tr:last-of-type` gives you two `<tr>` elements. `tr:last` will only ever give you one element.

Comment: Oh, I see. But it does not matter in my particular case. Given that important distinction, is my summarization correct?

Comment: @mark: If you disregard the difference then you are correct. But your initial question is all about the difference in the first place :)

Comment: Well, in my particular case there should have been no difference. The right answer is that `:last` is buggy and you sounded that answer.

Answer (score 5):

[`last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/CSS/%3alast-of-type) is a **CSS** pseudo-class, which represents the last sibling of the given tag name. It *may* work as a jQuery selector *if* the browser supports [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) and you're not using jQuery-only selectors; otherwise, it'll use Sizzle, which doesn't support it. See [this](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5543) jQuery ticket.

On the other hand, [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) is a **jQuery** selector, which selects the last matched element.

Comment: Probably worth noting that `:last-of-type` is not included in jQuery itself. When `querySelectorAll` fails (e.g. in older browsers) then a selector with that pseudoclass will fail.

Comment: More information on which CSS selectors aren't implemented in jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745274/what-css3-selectors-does-jquery-really-support-e-g-nth-last-child

Comment: @mark: Can you provide the exact markup for your table? With this markup, http://jsfiddle.net/6mues/, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

`:last-of-type` selects the last sibling with a specified tag name. Note that `:last-of-type` is not an "official" jQuery selector and only works in some browsers - specifically, those that support `document.querySelectorAll()` (newer versions of everything except IE).