# jQuery - Find nth last occurrence of element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I have the following HTMl structure, which i cannot change.

```
<div class="X">
    <ul>
        <li><a><img></a></li>
        <li><a><img></a></li>
        <li><a><img></a></li>
        <li><a><img></a></li>
        <li><a><img></a></li>
        <li><a><img></a></li>
        <li><a><img></a></li>
        <li><a><img></a></li>
        <li><a><img></a></li>
        <li><a><img></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The number of li items varies. I would like to select the nth element from the back and modify the img src.

This is what i have so far:

```
$('div.X').find('img').css('background-color', 'red');
```

I need some way to loop over the results of the .find and then somehow select the nth last element. I was thinking i should somehow reverse the list so i could just use the nth-child() selector.

I've found various other nth related questions, but i havn't been able to figure out how to nail this.

Any help is much appriciated.

Comment: Is the `nth` one different every time? Or is it always the `last - 1` or `last - 2`, etc...?

Comment: In my case it's actually the last -1, but figured i would write nth to make it easier for others to find and use.

Comment: Ok, now that the question is clearer, you could just use `$('.X li:nth-last-child(2) img').attr('src', 'newSrc');​` :-)

Comment: @andyb: Be careful: [`:nth-last-child()` is not supported by jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745274/what-css3-selectors-does-jquery-really-support-e-g-nth-last-child), despite being a CSS selector. If it works it's only because the browser supports it natively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go... http://jsfiddle.net/bYaRx/

I might have gone a little overboard with the implementation. I'm bored at work. Here's the relevant jQuery to get the correct img tag:

```
var $img = $('.X img');
$img.filter(':eq('+($img .length - (n+1))+')');
```

Comment: Awesome solution, works great. I didnt know the :eq selector. I ended using .eq() function, as it allows for using negative values. 

$('div.X').find('img').eq(-2).attr('src', newImg); 

Thanks alot for your quick and thorough help! Much appriciated, would have taken me forever :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.X img:eq(' + ($('div.X img').length - n) + ')')
```

Where `n` is how many back you want.

Note I used `:eq()` not `:nth-child()` - they are not the same.

Note2: There may be an off-by-one error here, so be sure to test it.