# How to select all elements except the first one inside a set of multiple matched elements in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

It must be late... Given the following HTML, how would one select all of the paragraphs except for the first paragraph inside each of the `div.thePost`s?

I have tried:

```
$('.thePost').children('p:gt(0)')
```

and

```
$('.thePost p:gt(0)')
```

and

```
$('.thePost > p:gt(0)')
```

All of which work fine for the very first `div.thePost` but end up selecting all other `<p>` tags within any other div with the class of `thePost`.

```
<div id="contentmiddle">

<div class="thePost">

  <h1>...</h1>

  <h3>...</h3>

  <span>...</span> 

  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>

</div><!-- /thePost -->

<div class="thePost">

  <h1>...</h1>

  <h3>...</h3>

  <span>...</span> 

  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>

</div><!-- /thePost -->

</div>​<!-- /contentmiddle -->
```

Comment: `$('.thePost').find('p:gt(0)')` http://jsfiddle.net/4TLv8/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`:first-of-type` is not a jQuery selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745274/what-css3-selectors-does-jquery-really-support-e-g-nth-last-child/11745367#11745367), so unless a browser supports it natively in CSS, the solutions using `:first-of-type` won't work.

If you need to support older browsers (IE < 9), you need to use [next siblings selector `~`](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector) instead:

```
$('.thePost > p ~ p')
```

Comment: @BoltClock Agree, beautiful! :) Thank you again. You get my vote.

Answer (score 4):

How about `$('.thePost > p:not(:first-of-type)')`

Comment: THANK YOU! (I shall now go read the documentation on :first-of-type.... Or go to bed...)

Comment: @jonny.milano: You won't find `:first-of-type` in the jQuery documentation... it's in the CSS spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#first-of-type-pseudo

Comment: @BoltClock ah thanks! Is that to say I can use any level 3 CSS selector in a modern version of jQuery?

Comment: @jonny.milano: Actually, no, not all of them. See the link in my answer for why.

Comment: Dang it! You stole my answer. :) gotta love css3 selectors.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('.thePost > p:not(:first)')
```

OR

```
$('.thePost').find('p:gt(0)')
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('.thePost p:not(:first-of-type)')`

Answer (score 0):

you can try too 
`$('p:gt(0)','.thepost'));`