# Check to see that a selector is accessible via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm looking at the selectors manual for jQuery, here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/.  It says, in the beginning, that CSS 1-3 selectors are supported, and then it goes on to list which selectors are supported.

I've been having trouble seeing whether or not `::selection` is selectable via jQuery.  If it isn't, is there a way to build in support for targeting `::selection` via jQuery?

Comment: Try it and see if it works?

Comment: There's actually an exhaustive list of selectors that jQuery *really* supports in this question: [What CSS3 selectors does jQuery really support, e.g. :nth-last-child()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745274/what-css3-selectors-does-jquery-really-support-e-g-nth-last-child) In my answer, I state that pseudo-elements are not supported; this means any selector with two colons before its name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately,  `::selection` cannot be used to select element or for that matter the selected text.

But you can get the selected text from the document using plain old JavaScript.

You can see a detailed blog post by Mark Kolich [here](http://mark.koli.ch/2009/09/use-javascript-and-jquery-to-get-user-selected-text.html) and a working [demo](http://mark.koli.ch/2009/09/05/get-selected-text-javascript.html)

Here is the code from that post

```
if(!window.Kolich){
  Kolich = {};
}

Kolich.Selector = {};
Kolich.Selector.getSelected = function(){
  var t = '';
  if(window.getSelection){
    t = window.getSelection();
  }else if(document.getSelection){
    t = document.getSelection();
  }else if(document.selection){
    t = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
  return t;
}

Kolich.Selector.mouseup = function(){
  var st = Kolich.Selector.getSelected();
  if(st!=''){
    alert("You selected:\n"+st);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).bind("mouseup", Kolich.Selector.mouseup);
});
```