# Use css selectors to parse an html string in node?

Tags: node.js, css-selectors, npm

I'm writing a scraper in node. Is there a module out there that will allow me to work with css selectors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the excellent [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom), and specifically [this section](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom#easymode-jsdomenv), where it shows how you can leverage jQuery in Node to scrape HTML documents, thus using the CSS-like selectors that jQuery offers.

Comment: Strictly speaking, as it leverages jQuery it makes use of jQuery selectors, so [some CSS3 selectors may not be available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745274/what-css3-selectors-does-jquery-really-support-e-g-nth-last-child), unless the native Selectors API is supported somehow...

Answer (score 4):

[Cheeriojs](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) is also a good alternative. It uses Jquery selectors engine.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is a module that allows you to use CSS selectors, I'd suggest having a look at [sel](https://github.com/amccollum/sel).

It supports CSS4 (!) selectors already (at least in parts), is smaller then Sizzle (jQuery's selector engine), and focuses on one task instead of doing everything somehow.

Comment: cool, I'm looking for server-side only but still cool

Comment: Can you post example code? For me, `node -r sel` crashes already, because it references an undefined variable [`document` in line 8](https://github.com/amccollum/sel/blob/addab28b60aa9ee217cfe9be63d58eb589b133c1/lib/sel.js#L8). This leads me to believe sel is intended to be used only in browsers, not node.js.

Answer (score 0):

[soupselect](https://github.com/harryf/node-soupselect) would be another choice. I was seeking a nodejs library which works like [nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/) in Ruby. You can perform css query not only over document but also over html fragments. soupselect is only a selector so, you also need [htmlparser2](https://github.com/fb55/htmlparser2) for parsing.