# When the url hash match a div's id then do something to the child of the div

Tags: jquery, html, css, url, fragment-identifier

Let's say I have the html as below:

```
<div class=".blog-item-holder">
<div id="AAAA"><div class="inner">AAAA</div></div>
<div id="BBBB"><div class="inner">BBBB</div></div>
<div id="CCCC"><div class="inner">CCCC</div></div> 
<div id="DDDD"><div class="inner">DDDD</div></div>
</div>
```

So reach of my url will be reset like this:

```
example.com/page/#AAAA
and
example.com/page/#BBBB
and
example.com/page/#CCCC
and
example.com/page/#DDDD
```

All I want is when people go to the page (for example: `example.com/page/#BBBB`) then the `div#BBBB .inner` will have a black back-ground, and same treatment for the url has has for CCCC, DDDD etc.

This is what I got so far on js:

```
if(window.location.hash) {
var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1),
    boxes = [];

$('.blog-item-holder > div').each(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('id') == hash) {
        $(this).children('div').css("background-color:#000000;");
    }
});
}
```

But somehow it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the correct syntax for **[.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)**:

```
$(this).children('div').css("background-color","#000000");
```

or:

```
$(this).children('div').css({"background-color":"#000000"});
```

instead of:

```
$(this).children('div').css("background-color:#000000;");
```

Comment: Hi thanks @Felix, sorry about the syntax but it still doesn't resolve the issue :(

Answer (score 1):

The `:target` pseudo-class is specifically designed for this sort of situation. No need to query `window.location.hash` using a script — the following CSS will be applied on-the-fly:

```
:target > .inner {
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

If you must use jQuery for compatibility with old browsers that don't support `:target` in CSS, you can still use it in a jQuery selector if you're using version 1.9 or later (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745274/what-css3-selectors-does-jquery-really-support-e-g-nth-last-child/11745367#11745367) for more details). Note that, as mentioned, the problem lies in your `.css()` argument so you need to fix that:

```
$(':target > .inner').css("background-color", "#000000");
```

Again, no need to query `window.location.hash` here, unless you need to use the hash fragment for other purposes. The entire `if` block can be replaced with this single statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are making mistake of assign css properties via Jquery, you need to assign properties using key , value in .css()

Try to debug what value you getting for hash first

```
if(window.location.hash) {
var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1),
    boxes = [];

$('.blog-item-holder').find('.inner').each(function(){
    if ($(this).parent().attr('id') == hash) {
        $(this).css("background-color","#000000");
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This must work :)

```
$(window).on('hashchange',function(){
  var _child = $(location.hash).children('.inner');
  _child.css('backgroundColor', '#000');
})
```