# CSS "::" meaning

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm seeing this usage a lot. Specially with the pseudo classes.
What does "::" means in CSS?

```
.a_demo_three::before {
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Pseudo-elements):

> Sometimes you will see double colons (::) instead of just one (:).
>   This is part of CSS3 and an attempt to distinguish between
>   pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements. Most browsers support both values.

So, when you want to use [pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Pseudo-classes) like `:hover`, `:first-child` etc, use a single colon. If you want to use [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Pseudo-elements), like `::before`, `::after`, `::first-letter` and so on, use double colons.

---

One more note: the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-elements) states that browsers should only accept the `::` notation for pseudo-elements introduced in CSS 3, so you should follow the recommendations above :)

Comment: what is the difference between `:first-child` and `::first-letter` they both point to elements, what am I missing?

Comment: which browsers follow this strictly? do any fail to work with `::`?

Comment: I don't think so, but I remember that the `placeholder` element required `::` in older FF/Chrome versions. @Itay `first-letter`will target the first letter of the element, not the first element

Comment: Still, it targets a real element, while :hover is an event...and it is Itay, no L ;-)

Comment: Ok - went over the docs. `::first-child` is definitely part of the "pseudo-elements" : describes states (events) and :: real elements, which are always there.

Comment: It's not. `first-child` describes the state too, ie. the element is currently the first child of X. While `first-letter` describes a "virtual" element that should always be there

Comment: and what user action would I do on the page to change that state of first-child?

Comment: You could move the element around with javascript. That's not possible on pseudo-elements

Comment: Thank you for the reply, and great discussion going on here!

Comment: @One Trick Pony: Only Firefox required double colons - it's changed to a single colon as of version 19 I believe. Chrome has always used a single colon.

Comment: @Itay Moav -Malimovka: `:hover` is *not* an event, it's a *state*, just like `:first-child`. Events and states are two very different things; see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703241/does-css-have-a-blur-selector-pseudo-class/11703334#11703334) for more. `::first-letter` is a virtual element that's created as a "child" of a real element.

Comment: @Nico: IE8 and older do not understand the double-colon syntax. If you must support older browsers, use single colons for `:first-letter`, `:first-line`, `:before` and `:after`. If you don't need to, use double colons as recommended by W3C.