# reverse hover on anchor tag on mouse leave

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to reverse this animation direction on mouseleave ?

i tried to add a mouseleave even to .link but it stops the hovering

```css
.link { 
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 100px;
}
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
}
.link:hover .box {
  transform: translateX(0)
}
```

```html
<a class="link">
  item
  <span class="box"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "reversing the animation" when you leave? When you leave the animation reverses itself already.

Comment: @KaseyChang reverse the direction from left to right instead of right to left

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15194324/2279082

Comment: So when the hover starts, you want it to "slide in" from the right, but when you leave hover, you want it to "slide out" from the LEFT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `scale` combined with `transform-origin` it's possible:

```css
.link {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 100px;
}

.link::after {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease-in, transform-origin 0s 0.4s;
}

.link:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: right;
}
```

```html
<a class="link">
  item
</a>
```

Related question to get different ideas using background: [How to animate underline from left to right?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54616139/8620333)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.link { 
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 100px;
}
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
}
.link:hover .box {
  transform: translateX(0)
}
```

```html
<a class="link">
  item
  <span class="box"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: This is not what the OP was looking for.. OP meant transition in from left to right and transition out to the same direction. Think of a car coming from left to right, stopping and then continue the same way