# Use CSS to style HTML select after a selection has been made

Tags: html, css, html-select

I am looking for an opposite of select:focus, something that would style the select from CSS after a selection is made.

concept:

```
select:when not focused
{
    color:transparent;
}
```

Comment: Check ["Does CSS have a :blur selector ( pseudo-class )?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703241/does-css-have-a-blur-selector-pseudo-class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/%3anot) pseudo-class and combine it with the `:focus` one. Something like this should work:

```
select:not(:focus) {
  color: red;
}
```

Here's a **demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/b2rnU/1

Comment: Updated demo, you missed a colon.

Answer (score 1):

do u mean on `focusout`

```
$("element").focusout(function() { ... });
```

Comment: Neither JavaScript, nor jQuery tags are present, why to propose such solution?

Comment: No - i just wanted to use basic css to give that effect - thanks

Answer (score 1):

Editing to what @Pzin said, add a new class with select to get what you want.

Like

```
select:focus {
  background: white;
}
```