# Changing label border-color when input:focus

Tags: css

With just CSS I want do change the `<label>` border-color when **input:focus**.

HTML:

```
<label for="s">
        <input name="s" placeholder="search">
</label>
```

CSS:

```
label { 
      border: 3px solid red; /* THIS SHOULD CHANGE */
}

input:focus ~ label {
       border-color: yellow; /* WHEN "input:blur" <label> border-color should be yellow */
}
```

Here what I did until now: **http://jsfiddle.net/s6Zc9/2/**

Thank you.

Comment: as far as i know there is no :blur pseudo-class in CSS

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I mean "focus". Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're looking for a css parent selector, which also doesn't exists. You could do it with jquery

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s6Zc9/3/)**

```
$("label input").on("focus blur",function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("focused");
});

.focused{
    border-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: After your comment I updated the question. I made a mistake, but ":focus" is what I really want to use. Anyway, thank you for your solution. I will wait for some CSS-only answer, but yours is the best so far. Thank you very much! =)

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no :blur pseudo-class in CSS.

The dynamic pseudo-classes in CSS represent states; they don't represent events or transitions between states in terms of the DOM. To wit: the :focus pseudo-class represents an element that is in focus; it does not represent an element that has just received focus, nor does there exist a :blur pseudo-class to represent an element that has just lost focus.

Similarly, this applies to the :hover pseudo-class. While it represents an element which has a pointing device over it, there is neither a :mouseover pseudo-class for an element that has just been pointed to nor a :mouseout pseudo-class for an element that has just been pointed away from.

If you need to apply styles to an element that is not in focus, you have two choices:

```
Use :not(:focus) (with less browser support):

input:not(:focus), button:not(:focus) {
    /* Styles for only form inputs and buttons that do not have focus */
}
```

Declare a rule that applies to any element regardless of its focus state, and override for elements that have focus:

```
input, button {
    /* Styles for all form inputs and buttons */
}

input:focus, button:focus {
    /* Styles for only form inputs and buttons that have focus */
}
```

THIS ANSWER WAS ORIGINALLY POSTED BY BOLTCLOCK ([HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703241/does-css-have-a-blur-selector-pseudo-class))

Comment: Hello. It was a mistake of mine. I want to use :focus. Sorry! :(