# Can I apply a CSS transition on hover-out only?

Tags: css, hover, css-transitions

The CSS transition property lets you animate on both hover-in & hover-out if you put the transition as below:

```
#inner{
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity 2000ms;
}
#outer:hover #inner{
    opacity:1;
}
```

However, if the transition is moved to `:hover` state, it only happens on hover-in.

```
#inner{
    opacity:0;
}
#outer:hover #inner{
    opacity:1;
    transition:opacity 2000ms;
}
```

Is it possible to do the reverse, i.e. animate on hover-out only?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's one way to achieve this (put a <strike>`bogus` property</strike> `none` for transition property in `:hover`):

```
#inner2{
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity 2000ms;
}
#outer:hover #inner2{
    opacity:1;
    transition:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j716sbav/4/

Answer updated to incorporate @BoltClock's suggestion. Putting `none` instead of a bogus property is definitely more elegant.

Comment: While this works, the more "correct" way of doing this, so to speak, is to use `none` instead of a bogus property. Note that you can specify this using either the longhand `transition-property: none` or the shorthand `transition: none`.

Answer (score 8):

If you prefer not to specify the `transition` property more than once, you can apply the transition to `:not(:hover)`, [but the caveat is that you need to swap all of the other declarations as well](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/j716sbav/5):

```
#inner2{
    opacity:1;
}
#outer:not(:hover) #inner2{
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity 2000ms;
}
```

Either of these will work, but if you don't want to deal with confusing inversions, stick with overriding via `transition: none`.

Also note that [CSS selectors represent states and not events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703241/does-css-have-a-blur-selector-pseudo-class), which means that it utilizes a `:hover` state rather than mouseover and mouseout events; however, a transition from `:hover` to `:not(:hover)` is essentially the CSS way of expressing a mouseout animation.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old post but, as it came up in response to my Google search on the subject, I thought I'd post my solution.

After reading everything posted here, I found the simplest solution. Place a transition on the initial state as follows:

```
.btn {
  opacity:0;
  transition:0.6s;
}

.btn:hover {
  opacity:1;
  transition:0.8s;
}
```

So it has a transition time to the hover state and a transition time to the non-hover (ie normal) state. Saves a whole bunch of code.