# How can I affect one div's css if it is not child of the one I hover on?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```
<body>
    <div class="col-md-6" >
        <h1>This is the element I want to :hover on</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" >
        <div id="python">
            This is the hidden element I want to make appear
        </div> 
    </div>
</body>
```

If possible I would like to do it only with CSS.

Thank you.

[image: That's another example where I want to change Borja's font-size]

That's another example where I want to change Borja's font-size on `.main:hover`

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30835168/is-there-an-opposite-css-pseudo-class-to-hover

Comment: div:hover:not(#pyhton) {  color: green; } //CSS Negation... not used it myself but something like that

Comment: That is not what I am looking for @Dammeul. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Themes.guide can you check again if this is a duplicate? I have inserted an image that I think it explains better what I want

Comment: Yes it's a dupe as [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered) explains all you need to know, and that it's not possible for the child of a sibling to affect the child of another sibling because there is no parent CSS selector. You can however, hover a sibling and affect the child element of another sibling. https://www.codeply.com/go/uPHi9iqXsd

Comment: Thank you @Themes.guide, that solved all my doubts.