# Want to add class when hover the div with Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add a class when hovering the any of this div, but not the hovering one, I mean if I hover over the number 2 div, the class will be added to the number 1 and number 3 div, if I hover over the number 3 class will be added to 1 and 2, is this possible?

```
<div> 1 </div>
<div> 2 </div>
<div> 3 </div>
```

Comment: If you don't explain what is that you're trying to achieve exactly, this is nothing more than an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) - because sometimes a problem - knowing the exact peculiarities can be solved by other means - sometimes not with the tools you initially intended to. Also, please read [ask].

Comment: Does this answers your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30835337/383904

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan  He wanted it to be done in vanilla javascript, not css.

Comment: when hovering one div, I want to add class to the other two divs, the code I got from here works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions: the first using CSS and the second using JS.

As you can see from [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30835337/383904), JS is not needed:

```css
.wrapper:hover div:not(:hover) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

but if you really insist in using JS:

- Use [mouseenter and mouseleave](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) events
- Use [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) and its respective methods

```js
const elDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper div");

const toggleClassDivs = (evt) => {
  const isEnter = evt.type === "mouseenter";
  elDivs.forEach(el => el.classList[isEnter ? "add" : "remove"]("red"));
  evt.currentTarget.classList.remove("red");
};

elDivs.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("mouseenter", toggleClassDivs);
  el.addEventListener("mouseleave", toggleClassDivs);
});
```

```css
.red {background: red;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use events `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` and inside them use `for` to go through all divs and when `index === i` (i = index = index of hovering div) then just continue and don't add class. Like that.

```js
let divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");

divs.forEach((div, index) => {
   div.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
     toggleClass(divs, index, true)
   })
   div.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
      toggleClass(divs, index, false)
   })
})

function toggleClass(divs, index, add){
   for(let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
        if(i === index) continue;
        add ? divs[i].classList.add("red") : divs[i].classList.remove("red");
   }
}
```

```css
.red {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div> 1 </div>
<div> 2 </div>
<div> 3 </div>
```

Comment: If you **don't know what you're doing** avoid the use of `mouseover` and `mouseout`. Use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead. Or rather given the unexplained specific setting - just use CSS `:hover`.

Answer (score 0):

I have added comments in the code below to help you follow what is going on. In my example I use the `event.target` to get the ***parent element*** of the `event.target` and its ***sibling div elements***. Then you write a conditional that checks if the `event.target` is equal to the div element queried using its ***parent element*** if the current iteration through the loop is not the `event.target`, we add the class to style the other divs not being targeted, else we have the `event.target` => we remove the class.

Lastly we loop over the event target types and divs adding the event listener and callback method.

```js
// query the div nodeList
let divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
// array for the event types
const events = ["mouseover", "mouseout"];

// method for toggling your classes
function toggleClass(e) {
  // get the parentNode of your event.target element and then query the div elements using that parentNode
  // also check that the event.target is not one of the div elements => e.target !== el, 
  // then check the event.type and add/remove class accordingly
  e.target.parentNode.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(el => e.target !== el ?
    e.type === "mouseover" ? el.classList.add('change-bg') : el.classList.remove('change-bg') : null)
}

// loop over events and div elements and pass your callback method
events.forEach(ev => {
  divs.forEach(div => {
    div.addEventListener(ev, toggleClass)
  })
})
```

```css
.change-bg {
  background-color: green;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  color: yellow;
}

div {
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div> 1 </div>
<div> 2 </div>
<div> 3 </div>
```