# Opposite of CSS Selector:hover?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

If I would like to make an animation when a user hovers their mouse over an `<a>` tag, all I need is `:hover`.

However, if I want to do something when the user gets their mouse off of the `<a>`, the rules will apply. ***I do not want the animation to play before you hover***, as in `a { animation: name 1s linear reverse }`, but I want it to play ***ONLY*** after the user ***stops hovering***.

Comment: You'll need javascript for this.

Comment: [`onMouseOut`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseout.asp)

Comment: or using mouseleave.

Comment: It *may* be possible to do this with a transition instead of an animation, but it depends on what exactly you're trying to animate and how. It's not always possible. It would help if you could specify this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using javascript by adding a `mouseover` event on the element, then add a ***class*** on the `event.target` that has the animation attached to it. If you want this to be infinite, in terms of every time the user mouses out, then you can set a `setTimeout` and remove the class from the element using the same duration of your CSS animation.

```js
//get the element from the DOM using its id attribute
const hoverme = document.getElementById('hoverme')

// create an event listener for mouseout  
// and pass the event into the function --> e
hoverme.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
  // now get the current event.target --> e.target
  // and add the class that has the animation attached to it
  e.target.classList.add('anim-class')
  // remove the animation class using setTimeout
  // with a duration that is the same as that set in the 
  // css animation, in my example it is 2 seconds --> 2000ms
  setTimeout(()=>{
    e.target.classList.remove('anim-class')
  }, 2000) //<-- 2 seconds or 2000ms
})
```

```css
#hoverme {
  color: #000;
}

#hoverme:hover {
  color: #0FF;
}

.anim-class {
  animation: rotate 2s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="hoverme">
  Hover over this
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A method without js would be to wrap the element you want to animate in a div and set that div to `visibility: hidden` by using a keyframes. Then set the animation for the same time as the actual animation for the element you are animating. This will hide the element during animation on initial load. Then you can use the `:not` selector to do what you want to animate it after every time you stop hovering.

```css
#container {
  animation: hidden 1s linear 1;
}
#block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  
}

div:not(:hover) {
  animation: grow 1s linear; 
}

@keyframes grow {
  to {width: 100px;}
}

@keyframes hidden {
  from {visibility: hidden;}
  to {visibility: hidden;}
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="block"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the opposite of hover is actually the initial state
so you go like that

```
.class{
// not hover
}

.class:hover{
// when hover
}
```

Comment: Yes, but If i play an animation it will run when the site loads or the element loads.

Comment: ah i see then , you will need another css class , and you add an eventlistener on that elemnt to apply the style once mouse-leave

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703241/does-css-have-a-blur-selector-pseudo-class for an explanation on events vs states.